# NOT NULL arroja cadena vacía

Tags: mysql, sql, null

Hacía días que comencé con un curso SQL en MySQL, y estoy con el atributo NOT NULL.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
create database if not exists INSTRUMENTOS;
use INSTRUMENTOS;

create table if not exists GUITARRAS(
    id tinyint unsigned auto_increment,
    marca varchar(20) not null,
    modelo varchar(20) default 'Desconocido',
    precio smallint unsigned not null,
    primary key(id)
```

Sin embargo, pongo a prueba la sintaxis ejecutando:

```
insert into GUITARRAS(modelo) values('Soloist');
```

Y entiendo debería generar error, pues los datos insertados no incluye ni marca ni precio, por lo tanto no debería permitir avanzar hasta que se insertara dicha información.

Sin embargo, sólo me arroja WARNING's y aún así registra la información.

```
12:50:06    insert into GUITARRAS(modelo) values('Soloist') 1 row(s) affected, 2 warning(s): 1364 Field 'marca' doesn't have a default value 1364 Field 'precio' doesn't have a default value   0.000 sec
```

Al ejecutar:

```
select * from GUITARRAS;
```

Me muestra:

```
# numero_de_inventario  marca   modelo  precio
          1                    Soloist    0
```

Me muestra cadena vacía en marca y 0 en precio, cuando entiendo ni siquiera debería permitir ejecutar la sentencia insert.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Precisamente al ser campos que no permiten nulos, el gestor de base de datos en el campo numerico(precio) lo inserta como un cero, que es un valor no nulo, y el campo marca te lo rellena con espacios en blanco, es decir se guardan como no nulos, ya que el 0 es un valor y el espacio aunque no se ve tambien es un valor posible en un varchar, campo nulo es otra cosa, es que en ese campo no se guarda absolutamente nada, no ocupa espacio fisico, es sencillamente nada. Y en este caso el 0 y el espacio si son datos que persisten.

Comment: O sea realmente se te cumple tu restriccion de no nulos, ya que no permite insertas datos nulos, se les pone un valor por defecto, 0 para los numeros, espacios para los varchar, las fechas tendran otros valores por defecto al igual que el resto de los campos de la bd

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict
*"If strict mode is not in effect, MySQL inserts adjusted values for invalid or missing values and produces warnings."

Comment: @Japv y ese comportamiento de MySQL es, en mi opinión, desastroso; además está fuera del estándar SQL. Cualquier otro motor, si no tiene valores default, dará error al tratar de insertar un registro sin indicar un valor explícito para un campo `not null`, así que es el tipo de cosas que te _sorprenden_ de MySQL cuando te lo topas.

Comment: @jachguate, a mi tampoco me gusta MySQL, y pensar que hay gente que lo compara con Oracle o Sql Server,  sin palabras

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas.
 @N.N. utilicé de guía el texto del link que anexaste.

 Mi MySQL tenía ese comportamiento distinto debido a que estaba deshabilitado el modo estricto 
 Lo habilité entrando a phpmyAdmin/Variables/SQL Mode e insertando lo siguiente: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

 Para desactivarlo ocupamos:
 NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Answer (score 2):

Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas.
@N.N. utilicé de guía el texto del link que anexaste.
Mi MySQL tenía ese comportamiento distinto debido a que estaba deshabilitado el modo estricto.

Lo habilité entrando a *phpmyAdmin/Variables/SQL Mode* e insertando lo siguiente: **`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`**

Para desactivarlo ocupamos:

**`NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`**

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido. Yo tampoco conocía ese comportamiento de MySQL, probablemente implemente esa configuración que mencionaste.